# remote desktop connection kicks off OneNote on the local computer

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

On my employer's network, if I use the remote desktop to connect to computer X, I wind up with OneNote starting up on the local computer.  This only happens when connecting to computer X, no other.

I have no idea how this is happening.  I'm not a onenote user & so the result is annoying dialogs.

I've been through all the settings available if you hit the "options" button on the remote connect dialog--there is a "start the following program on connection" setting on the Programs tab, but that's unchecked & grayed out.

Interestingly, this setting seems to have followed me from one computer to another--I got issued a new laptop & it's happening on the new one as well as the old.  (My hostname is the same, but new hardware, new win7 image, etc.)

All machines are running 64-bit win7, if that's important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I still don't understand why this is happening, but I can eliminate the bad behavior.  If I un-check "Printers" on the Local Resources tab of the remote desktop connection dialog, I don't get the onenote process & its dialog.

I don't actually need to print from my remote session, and so this works for me.

Many thanks to user @gregg for asking good clarifying questions & suggesting things to look at/try.

Comment: Googling 'onenote remote desktop' brings up a TON of info, good self-solve though (bad both of us for not searching better). Make sure & mark your answer though so no other people try to answer. Kudos for the shout-out, but remember this is not a forum & they are pretty strict; that would be better done as a comment to my answer.
http://superuser.com/q/330898/160219
http://serverfault.com/q/390088/131761
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/onenote-opens-every-time-i-use-remote-desktop/91f5600d-18d4-4699-81a2-2eb9b5c77a4e

Comment: Sonufagun, you're right--and that search seems so obvious now.  Hindsight is 20/20, as always.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To be clear your PC (we'll call **PC~A**) is remoting to **PC~X** & Onenote starts? This doesn't happen when you (**PC~A**) connect to **PC~Y**? It's still happening when **PC~A** was upgraded (**PC~A1**)? I think you answered your own question its something isolated to **PC~X** & I'm guessing its something in the Startup (`msconfig`, Startup tab; else `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`)

Comment: First part is exactly right.  I don't think startup is a good explanation for what's happening though b/c OneNote is starting up on PC~A (and now PC~A1), not on PC~X.

Comment: That is weird, OneNote opens on your PC~A whenever you use MSTSC (RemoteDesktop)? And only when connecting to PC~X (no others)? I am perplexed too if that Programs tab is greyed out, maybe check box, wipe info, & check again? If you are using a RDP file (vs mstsc.exe directly), maybe that 'Programs' is saved in there (you can open RDP files with Notepad)

Comment: Yep--exactly right.  Good thought on checking that box &wiping info--just now tried that.  No difference.  It's obviously annoyance-level stuff--just so weird I'm curious how it's happening.

Comment: Are you using a .RDP file or mstsc.exe directly?

Comment: mstsc.exe directly.

Comment: Open hidden file: Documents\Default.RDP in notepad & confirm the following lines have nothing after the colon (maybe even delete the lines): 'alternate shell:s:' & 'shell working directory:s:'
I don't know what to tell you otherwise, I'm guessing its something residual somewhere as I don't see how it could follow you on two different PC's & only happen during connection to that one PC~X. The fact that you had something to erase on the Programs tab too...

Comment: Maybe delete some entries here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312169
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee483491%28v=winembedded.70%29.aspx

Comment: Default.rdp looks clean to me.  Here it is in its entirety: https://gist.github.com/rpardee/eb3be357c97b65040a0f

Comment: I'm now noticing a printer queue icon in the system tray when I make this connection.  I haven't actually added a printer to the new laptop yet & it looks like my default printer is a device called 'Adobe PDF'.  I wonder if that's related at all...

Comment: Process explorer says the onenote.exe process has command line onenote.exe /insertdoc "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\{9D5D5CDF-498C-498E-874B-619932F002B2}.xps" 131024464601020000.  That xps file exists, but is 0 bytes.  Parent process for onenote.exe is printfilterpipelinesvc.exe(41660).  Screwy stuff.  Anyhoo--thanks for your help Gregg!

Comment: Remember to upvote my answer & accept it if you believe it solved your issue or got you near it